# Cast dynamic to ValueType

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, resharper

I have a dynamic object, I check that it's a value type and if it is I pass it to a method to handle value types.

```
if (type.IsValueType)
{
     _valueTypeRenderer.RenderValueType(propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null));
}
```

`RenderValueType()` has the following signiture:

```
void RenderValueType<T>(T item) where T : struct;
```

The app compiles, by Resharper is moaning:

`The type 'dynamic' must be non-nullable value type in order to use it as a parameter 'T'`

So...

Is my IsValueType enough of a check  and Resharper is wrong, or is Resharper right and I need to do a clever cast?

Comment: Well, have you tried running the app and seeing what's happening?

Comment: In my opinion at first you have to tell your method which type you are using. _valueTypeRenderer.RenderValueType<myType>(propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null));

Comment: @decPL Yup, tests all pass, so far nothing bad, like I said, just wondered if there was a better way.

Comment: What's `item` declared as?